# beamercolorbox columns

Tags: beamer

I have a presentation with a header with beamercolor box. However, I want to make the header in two columns, so I can put a logo on the left:

```
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.85\paperwidth,right]{section in head/foot}
    \rule{0.85\paperwidth}{1pt}
    %Vertikaler Abstand
    \vskip10pt
    %Fügt die Standard-Navi ein (miniframes)
    \insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}
    \vskip8pt
    \rule{0.85\paperwidth}{0.5pt}
    \vskip27.5pt % same height of the example provided, but IMHO is too much
    \rule{0.85\paperwidth}{1pt}
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

So instead of this being only 0.85 of the width, I want it to be the whole width and to have two columns within it. Any ideas how to do this?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume that with "header" you are talking about the `headline` template. Your current settings are: two horizontal stripes separated by three horizontal rules. Where exactly should the logo go and in what position? Shoul it be positioned within the upper stripe? Shout it be placed on its own and have a height equal to the height of the current headline?  Your description is not precise. Can you make a drawing (by hand, if you want) showing the exact layout you are trying to achieve? You can upload the image elsewhere ([imgur](http://imgur.com/), for example) and provide the link here.

Comment: To be able to answer this, I think we need something like the mock-up Gonzalo suggests.